# Swift Add Button to SCNNode

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, xcode9-beta

I'm playing around with the ARKit and image detection.
Now I have an app that detects images an places planes on the screen where the detected objects are.

How can I add a clickable element like a button on the planes. I want to have a click event on each detected object.

This is what my renderer function looks:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
        updateQueue.async {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                                 height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

            planeNode.opacity = 0.25
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            planeNode.runAction(self.imageHighlightAction)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let imageName = referenceImage.name ?? ""
            self.statusViewController.cancelAllScheduledMessages()
            // self.statusViewController.showMessage("Detected image “\(imageName)”")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let second = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoViewController")as! InfoViewController
            second.myStringValue = imageName
            // self.navigationController?.pushViewController(second, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways you can approach this:

1: **Standard Approach**:

In your `delegate` method, assign each node a name as per below (clearly if you have lots of nodes you would want to store them in an Array or Dictionary depending upon your needs):

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. Check We Have The Image Anchor
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    //2. Get The Reference Image
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

    //1. Create The Plane Geometry With Our Width & Height Parameters
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                         height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

    //2. Create A New Material
    let material = SCNMaterial()

    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

    //3. Create The Plane Node
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

    planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = material

    planeNode.opacity = 0.25

    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    //4. Add A Name To The Node
    planeNode.name = "I Was Clicked"

    //5. Add It To The Scene
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)

}
```

Then using `touchesBegan`, perform a hitTest and handle your touch accordingly:

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    /*
     1. Get The Current Touch Location
     2. Check That We Have Touched A Valid Node
     3. Check If The Node Has A Name
     4. Handle The Touch
     */

    guard let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: augmentedRealityView),
        let hitNode = augmentedRealityView?.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil).first?.node,
        let nodeName = hitNode.name
        else {
            //No Node Has Been Tapped
            return

    }
    //Handle Event Here e.g. PerformSegue
    print(nodeName)

}
```

2: **An Interesting Approach:**

`UIKit` elements can actually be added as an `SCNGeometry's Material`. I personally haven't seen many people use this approach, but it may prove useful to anyone who wants to incorporate `UIKit` with `ARKit`.

Create A Custom UIButton e.g:

```
/// Clickable View
class ClickableView: UIButton{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(objectTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.backgroundColor = .red

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

/// Detects Which Object Was Tapped
///
/// - Parameter sender: UIButton
@objc func objectTapped(_ sender: UIButton){

    print("Object With Tag \(tag)")

   }

}
```

And in your delegate method do the following:

```
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. Check We Have The Image Anchor
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    //2. Get The Reference Image
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

    //1. Create The Plane Geometry With Our Width & Height Parameters
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                         height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

    //2. Create A New Material
    let material = SCNMaterial()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //3. Create The New Clickable View
        let clickableElement = ClickableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                                           width: 300,
                                                           height: 300))
        clickableElement.tag = 1

        //4. Add The Clickable View As A Materil
        material.diffuse.contents = clickableElement
    }

    //5. Create The Plane Node
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

    planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = material

    planeNode.opacity = 0.25

    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    //6. Add It To The Scene
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

This should get you started...

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.

Comment: The second approach is really nice. For anyone that tries to implement it, and wants to navigate via present/push to other screens, note that SceneKit creates new `UIWindow` objects for every such UIKit element you assign to a material, that's how it sends events to be handled. So take care that you make the necessary cleanup to avoid unwanted behaviour (e.g. you can iterate over the `UIApplication.shared.windows` and hide the windows which are not key).